# How to configure the user_token of Damn Vulnerable Web Application within CSRF field while Script based authentication using ZAP?

Tags: security, owasp, zap, penetration-testing, security-testing

I had been following the documentation of [Script Based Authentication](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/api/#script-based-authentication) for Damn Vulnerable Web Application using ZAP. I have navigated to `http://localhost/dvwa/login.php` through **Manual Explore** which opens up the *DVWA* application on my localhost as follows:

[image: dvwa_application]

and adds the URL to the *Default Context*.

I've also created the `dvwa` script with the following configuration:

[image: dvwa_script_configuration]

and modified the `dvwa` script:

[image: dvwa_script]

Now when I try *Configure Context Authentication*, `dvwa` script does gets loaded but the `CSRF` field doesn't shows up.

[image: dvwa_script_based_authentication]

Additionally, `POST Data` doesn't even shows up but `Extra POST Data` is shown.

Am I missing something in the steps? Can someone help me out?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The modified script within the documentation of [Script Based Authentication](https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/api/#script-based-authentication) section for Damn Vulnerable Web Application using ZAP

[image: auth_dvwa_zap_faulty_script]

seems incomplete.

The complete script is available at [Setting up ZAP to Test Damn Vulnerable Web App (DVWA)](https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/details/setting-up-zap-to-test-dvwa/) which is as follows:

```
function authenticate(helper, paramsValues, credentials) {
    var loginUrl = paramsValues.get("Login URL");
    var csrfTokenName = paramsValues.get("CSRF Field");
    var csrfTokenValue = extractInputFieldValue(getPageContent(helper, loginUrl), csrfTokenName);
    var postData = paramsValues.get("POST Data");

    postData = postData.replace('{%username%}', encodeURIComponent(credentials.getParam("Username")));
    postData = postData.replace('{%password%}', encodeURIComponent(credentials.getParam("Password")));
    postData = postData.replace('{%' + csrfTokenName + '%}', encodeURIComponent(csrfTokenValue));

    var msg = sendAndReceive(helper, loginUrl, postData);
    return msg;
}

function getRequiredParamsNames() {
    return [ "Login URL", "CSRF Field", "POST Data" ];
}

function getOptionalParamsNames() {
    return [];
}

function getCredentialsParamsNames() {
    return [ "Username", "Password" ];
}

function getPageContent(helper, url) {
    var msg = sendAndReceive(helper, url);
    return msg.getResponseBody().toString();
}

function sendAndReceive(helper, url, postData) {
    var msg = helper.prepareMessage();

    var method = "GET";
    if (postData) {
    method = "POST";
    msg.setRequestBody(postData);
    }

    var requestUri = new org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI(url, true);
    var requestHeader = new org.parosproxy.paros.network.HttpRequestHeader(method, requestUri, "HTTP/1.0");
    msg.setRequestHeader(requestHeader);

    helper.sendAndReceive(msg);

    return msg;
}

function extractInputFieldValue(page, fieldName) {
    // Rhino:
    var src = new net.htmlparser.jericho.Source(page);
    // Nashorn:
    // var Source = Java.type("net.htmlparser.jericho.Source");
    // var src = new Source(page);

    var it = src.getAllElements('input').iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
    var element = it.next();
    if (element.getAttributeValue('name') == fieldName) {
        return element.getAttributeValue('value');
    }
    }
    return '';
}
```

Using this script, `CSRF Field` and `POST Data` field shows up just perfect.

[image: dvwa_loaded]